# Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons not showing on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I've seen many questions and solutions for this issue on SO, but none have worked for me. The Glyphicons work great locally, but show as boxes on Heroku from desktop browsers.

I'm using them like this:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
```

This is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1.0'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.2.2'
gem 'simple_form'
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2.0"
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.32.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.7'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
gem "friendly_id", "~> 5.0.2"
gem 'faker', '1.2.0'
gem 'auto_html'
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'ckeditor', '~> 4.0.11'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development, :test do    
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

I currently have production.rb set like this after trying other fixes:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

My application.rb file has the following:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')

# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
config.assets.version = '1.0'

# Required for Devise on Heroku
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)
config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets
config.assets.precompile += %w(ckeditor/*)
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
config.assets.precompile += [ 'styles.css.scss']
config.assets.precompile += [
    'glyphicons-halflings.png',
    'glyphicons-halflings-white.png'
  ]
```

I have also tried running

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

I have tried so many fixes, that something I have set now might be wrong. Everything works great locally. I also have an issue where a text-align: center is not being pushed to heroku from my CSS file. I'll post that as a separate issue, but I mention it in case it's a related issue with the asset pipeline.

This is how I load teh stylesheets in the app:

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

These are my stylesheets:

```
application.css.scss
pages.css.scss
posts.css.scss
scaffolds.css.scss
styles.css.scss
users.css.scss
```

in my application.css.scss:

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*= require font-awesome
```

in my styles.css.scss

```
@import 'bootstrap';
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");
@import 'font-awesome';


@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), 
    font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), 
    font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Here's the error from Chrome:

Font from origin 'http://thetens.herokuapp.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.thetens.us' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
jquery-91eecca5c0fff73b540ae82e1b1833c8.js:3581 GET http://thetens.herokuapp.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff jquery-91eecca5c0fff73b540ae82e1b1833c8.js:3581 (anonymous function)jquery-91eecca5c0fff73b540ae82e1b1833c8.js:3120 firejquery-91eecca5c0fff73b540ae82e1b1833c8.js:3232 self.fireWithjquery-91eecca5c0fff73b540ae82e1b1833c8.js:3444 jQuery.extend.readyjquery-91eecca5c0fff73b540ae82e1b1833c8.js:3475 completed
(index):1 Font from origin 'http://thetens.herokuapp.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.thetens.us' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
(index):1 GET http://thetens.herokuapp.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf

Update: I commented out

```
# config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://thetens.herokuapp.com"
```

and now I only get two errors:

GET http://www.thetens.us/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff jquery-6156cfcaa88efb694ac4fac3d8cef9c4.js:3581 (anonymous function)jquery-6156cfcaa88efb694ac4fac3d8cef9c4.js:3120 firejquery-6156cfcaa88efb694ac4fac3d8cef9c4.js:3232 self.fireWithjquery-6156cfcaa88efb694ac4fac3d8cef9c4.js:3444 jQuery.extend.readyjquery-6156cfcaa88efb694ac4fac3d8cef9c4.js:3475 completed
(index):1 GET http://www.thetens.us/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf

Comment: Look at the style sheet make sure that the absolute path make sure that they are linking properly

Comment: @MZaragoza My CSS works great in general, and everything works locally, so is it possible that they aren't linked properly?

Comment: Yes, make sure that in the css file that you call the fonts it starts with "/assets/..."

Comment: @MZaragoza I added stylesheet info above. I just load it with the stylesheet_link_tag. Is there more info that I'm missing in regards to the path?

Comment: Can you post what is in *= require font-awesome

Comment: @MZaragoza That's the font-awesome-rails gem. I tried using those as a substitute for the glyphicons when they wouldn't work. The problem began before that, but I could possibly remove those if need be. I also added some additional stylesheet info above.

Comment: I ended up just using font-awesome. I would love to figure this out anyways, because I'm sure someone else will benefit. I'll keep working on it.

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked out:

**@import "bootstrap-sprockets";**
@import "bootstrap";

I hope this helps you to! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to link absolutely to the font like

```
  @import 'bootstrap';
  @import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");
  @import 'font-awesome';


  @font-face {
      font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
      src: font-path('/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
      src: font-path('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
font-path('/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), 
font-path('/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), 
font-path('/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
  }
```

Mark sure that the fonts are link properly in heroku

Comment: Isn't what you pasted as the answer the same code that I have in my question above? Sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: Look closely to the path of font it starts with '/assets' this has to be a absolute path to where the type face is loaded from

Comment: I see, sorry. I changed those paths, but it didn't fix it. I'll add the 404 that shows in Chrome above.

Comment: I have to ask what is the path of where the fonts live from.the root of your app

Comment: they're in /vendor/assets/fonts I tried changing the paths above to '/assets/fonts/' and '/vendor/assets/fonts/' but neither worked

Comment: Check if ' /assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot' is a good path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68034/discussion-between-tony-tambe-and-mzaragoza).

Comment: Put that on the url Http://appname.com/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot

Comment: It says the page doesn't exist. I commented out the config.action_controller.asset_host and have less errors if that helps. I added it to the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on heroku and this is caused by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. That's why most config solutions don't work.

my solution was:

1. move all assets to S3 bucket ([used asset_sync gem](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync))
2. configureCORS on bucket ([CORS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html)) [IMPORTANT]